# mat-checkbox change event not returning checked value in onSubscriberCheck function

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using `mat-checkbox` of `Angular Material` and I have added a `change` event as below...

```
<div *ngFor="let subscriber of selectedSubscribers">
    <mat-checkbox (change)="onSubscriberCheck(subscriber)">
        {{ subscriber.name }}
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

The `onSubscriberCheck(subscriber)` code is as below...

```
onSubscriberCheck(subscriber: Subscribers) {
    if (subscriber.checked) {
        //Do Something
    } else {
        //Do Something else
    }
}
```

Here on click of the checkbox, I am always getting the value of `subscriber.checked` as `undefined`.

My expected result is, if it is checked, then the value should be `true` instead of `undefined`. If it is unchecked, then the value should be `false` instead of `undefined`.

**EDIT**

If I add `[(ngModel)]`, then the checkbox list does not work properly. Let me add the complete scenario...

I have 2 sets of checkbox lists. One is a set of `checked` checkbox list and below that one I will be showing a set of `unchecked` checkbox list. So, in `onSubscriberCheck(subscriber)` event, the `Do Something` is as below..

```
onSubscriberCheck(subscriber: Subscribers) {
    if (subscriber.checked) {
        this.selectedSubscribers.push(subscriber);
        this.unselectedSubscribers = this.unselectedSubscribers.filter(s => s.id !== subscriber.id);
    } else {
        this.unselectedSubscribers.push(subscriber);
        this.selectedSubscribers = this.selectedSubscribers.filter(s => s.id !== subscriber.id);
    }
}
```

So, here both `[(ngModel)] = subscriber.checked` and `change` event fires. How to overcome this one?

I just want to show the checked checkboxes at the top of the list and unchecked checkboxes at the bottom. So, on change event, I am rearranging the arrays `selectedSubscribers` and `unselectedSubscribers`

**SECOND EDIT**

I am using the below functions to populate the Subscribers

```
GetSelectedSubscribers() {
    this.selectedSubscribers = this.allSubscribers
      .filter(subscriber => subscriber.id !== undefined) 
      .map(subscriber => ({ id: subscriber.id, name: subscriber.name, checked: subscriber.checked }));
}

GetUnselectedSubscribers(){
    this.unselectedSubscriberGroupItems = this.subtractListIds(this.allSubscriberGroupItems, this.selectedSubscriberGroupItems);
    this.unselectedSubscribers = this.unselectedSubscriberGroupItems.lists.map(subscriber => ({ id: subscriber.id, name: subscriber.name, checked: subscriber.checked }));
}
```

Here the last checkbox name is coming as empty but has checkbox control. Don't know why it is not displaying..

Please clarify...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of the method `change`of the mat-checkBox is a `MatCheckboxChange`, see the [API](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api). Futhermore, you get this argument using $event

You can choose use the two binding [(ngModel)] or use the event (change) and the property [checked].

As Naren explain using ngModel, I want to show another approach. The idea is use an unique array and sort the array.

```
<div *ngFor="let subscribe of subscribers;let index=index">
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="subscribe.checked" 
                  (change)="subscribe.checked=$event.checked;sort()">
        {{ subscribe.name }}
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

where

```
  subscribers: any = [
    { checked: false, name: 'test'},
    { checked: false, name: 'test2'},
    ...
  ]
```

And the function sort

```
  sort()
  {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.subscribers.sort((a:any,b:any)=>
            (a.checked && b.checked) ||(!a.checked && !b.checked)?
                           a.name>b.name?1:-1:
             a.checked?-1:
             1)
    })
  }
```

It's necessary the setTimeout, else the mat-checkbox mark the position where we are.

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fxsrzk?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html)

Comment: Your code works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @CPK_2011, it's the same if you use `<mat-checkbox [ngModel]="subscribe.checked" (ngModelChange)="subscribe.checked=$event;sort()">`, but not forget import FormsModule -if is a standalone component in the imports array, if belong to a module in the module where you declare the component.

Comment: Hi @Eliseo, how to sort the array alphabetically for the first time when it loads? I used the `sort()` function in `onInit()` function. But it is not sorting..

Comment: just call to the function: `this.sort()`in ngOnInit or after you get the "subscribers"

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the `checked` variable to an `ngModel` please find below working example!

html

```
SELECTED
<div *ngFor="let subscriber of selectedSubscribers">
  <mat-checkbox
    [(ngModel)]="subscriber.checked"
    (ngModelChange)="onSubscriberCheck()"
  >
    {{ subscriber.name }}
  </mat-checkbox>
</div>
<br /><br />
UNSELECTED
<div *ngFor="let subscriber of unselectedSubscribers; trackBy: trackByFn">
  <mat-checkbox
    [(ngModel)]="subscriber.checked"
    (ngModelChange)="onSubscriberCheck()"
  >
    {{ subscriber.name }}
  </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';

/**
 * @title Configurable checkbox
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox-configurable-example',
  templateUrl: 'checkbox-configurable-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['checkbox-configurable-example.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
})
export class CheckboxConfigurableExample {
  allSubscribers: any = [
    {
      checked: false,
      name: 'test',
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      name: 'test2',
    },
  ];
  unselectedSubscribers: any = [];
  selectedSubscribers: any = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.unselectedSubscribers = this.allSubscribers;
  }

  onSubscriberCheck() {
    this.selectedSubscribers = this.allSubscribers.filter(
      (x: any) => x.checked
    );
    this.unselectedSubscribers = this.allSubscribers.filter(
      (x: any) => !x.checked
    );
  }

  trackByFn(i: number, val: any) {
    return val.name;
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/x1bfai)

Comment: Updated the Question. Please clarify.

Comment: @CPK_2011 please update full details, plz check now!

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. It works in stackblitz. But in my code still it is not completely working. When I remove `ngModel`, then this error does not occur. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: @CPK_2011 please modify the stackblitz with your code and the issue replicated! and share it to me

Comment: I am finding difficulty in creating a Stackblitz with my code. Could you please check my code in this question itself.