# Sorting of MatCheckbox list in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

Currently I am following the Answer mentioned in the below link

[matcheckbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77768904/mat-checkbox-change-event-not-returning-checked-value-in-onsubscribercheck-funct)

How can I achieve the sorting of checked checkboxes first in Alphabetical order and unchecked checkboxes second in Alphabetical order on click/unclick of the `mat-checkbox` control.

I would like to have sorting on 2 separate sets of checkboxes instead of only single `subscribers` for the Answer provided in the link above.

The name of the items can have Aplhanumeric characters.

Getting below error for the Answer provided..

[image: Error]

Displaying of Subscribers..

[image: Subscribers]

**EDIT**

Now, I am using this below code in the function of `sort()` and for the first time, on clicking of checkbox, it is automatically getting unchecked and for the 2nd time, it works..

```
sort()
{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.selectedSubscribers = this.allSubscribers
        .filter((x: any) => x.checked)
        .sort((a: any, b: any) => {
          return a.checked && b.checked ? a.name - b.name : 0;
      });
      this.unselectedSubscribers = this.allSubscribers
        .filter((x: any) => !x.checked)
        .sort((a: any, b: any) => {
          return a.checked && b.checked ? a.name - b.name : 0;
      });
    })
}
```

**SECOND EDIT**

Getting the below error when I use `BrowserModule` in Submodule

[image: BrowserModule]

Comment: @Eliseo, Please help me on this. I am little bit confused with the `sort()` function mentioned in the other post related to mat-checkbox.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-csaqn7?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html (sorry for the null explained, I'm in hurry). If we have number we can use a.id-b.id, but if you have string you need reutnr 1 and -1 according a.name>b.name or not)

Comment: For the first time it adds an empty row at the top with no checkbox control and its name on click of any checkbox at the bottom. And for the next time, it works by sorting and checking at the top. I am not using a standalone component. That is the only difference.

Comment: Still it is not working perfectly..

Comment: Check if you have errors in console. Take carefull, when you use (ngModel), you use `subscribe.checked=$event`, if you use (change) you use `subscribe.checked=$event.checked`. -see the "checked"- really it's the same use standalone or not. Check also if you import the BrowserAnimation -Material need "animation"-.

Comment: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-urtxky?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts,main.ts) the same code in modules

Comment: It's already used in `app.module.ts` for both `BrowserModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule`. It is not allowing me to add in `SubModule`. Also, I am using `change` with `$event.checked` properly. Updated the Question with the Error Details.

Comment: It is becoming very hard to find out where it is going wrong. You previous example worked perfectly. Suddenly when I divide the `allSubscribers` into `selected` and `unselected` it is working akwardly.

Comment: It works perfectly with single `subscribers` list when I just changed the `div` tag and the related `sort` function. But when I divide it into 2 `subscribers` list like `selectedSubscribers` and `unselectedSubscribers`, it goes out of the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort function should return 1 (if less), -1(if more) or 0 (if equal). We need take carefull when use concatenated ternary operators. If you have two separates arrays only use the property name:

```
sort((a:any,b:any)=>a.name>b.name?1:a.name<b.name?-1:0
```

It's the same like

```
sort((a:any,b:any)=>{
   if (a.name>b.name)
      return 1
   else{
     if (a.name<b.name)
        return -1
     }
     else
        return 0
  }
}
```

Or if we can not concatenate else -a return yet return a value-

```
sort((a:any,b:any)=>{
   if (a.name>b.name)
      return 1

   if (a.name<b.name)
        return -1

   return 0
}
```

Well, we know that there no two objects with the same name, so we can simplify

```
sort((a:any,b:any)=>a.name>b.name?1:-1
```

Comment: I am missing something here.. Could you please provide Stackblitz example for this..? Now on click of any checkbox for the first time, it is unchecking itself. Then for the 2nd time, it is checking and moving to the top.

Comment: Updated my code in the Question.. Waiting for your reply... Please help..